# Centrar un div no fixed como div fixed con animación de transición

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy tratando de hacer un div que cuando haces clic cambie de estar envuelto dentro de un div junto a un párrafo, para salirse del contenedor y posicionarse en el centro de la pantalla siguiendo el desplazamiento del scroll, pero como no es posible hacer una animación que cambie de posición no fixed a fixed, no sé cómo es posible hacer esto.

[Image in initial state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpgBX.png)

[Image in final state](https://gyazo.com/cbfa8ca2b92bd0a948bd3e21de1c66d8)

Normalmente las soluciones a otras preguntas que encuentro son soluciones para cada caso específico ya que no hay una forma general de hacer esta transición desde diferentes tipos de posiciones

Comment: la publicacion debe ser en Español

Comment: editado, gracias, no me di cuenta de que estaba haciéndolo en una versión española de stackoverflow

Comment: Bueno. Si es al evento click debes hacerlo con javascript cambiando a position fixed y para centrarlo usar top,left,right y bottom. Si el div no debe volver a la posicion inicial con eso basta. Sino debes hacer un toggl

Comment: Pero si cambio el estilo por ejemplo para que pase de relative a fixed, sea como fuere, no se ve una transición desde donde estaba ubicado hasta el estado final, que es lo que ando buscando. Basicamente se teletransporta. y solo se anima el crecimiento de tamaño.